# get id of post from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, unique-id

i have posts in a table each with a unique id. I want to use this id to have a user delete his or her post from a mysql table. how can i find out the unique id of the table?

```
while($posts=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
$tasks=$posts['task'];
$time=$posts['time'];
$date=$posts['date'];
$imp=$posts['important'];
$del=$posts['delete'];
$id=$posts['id'];

//define delete button
$button='<form method="post" action="remindMe.php"><input type="submit" value="Delete Post" name="delete" id='.$id.' /></form>';


if($imp==0 && $del != 0){
echo '<p id="tasks">'.$tasks. '</p><p id="date">'.$date.'</p><p id="time">'.$time.'</p>'.$button.'     <hr />';
}
}


 //see if button is clicked
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  $query="UPDATE `task` SET `delete`=0 WHERE `id`='/*id from mysql table*/'";
  mysqli_query($con, $query)
    or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Add the id as a hidden input to your form that is subitted when the Delete button is pressed.

Comment: Post the id from the form and retrieve it in submit and then do the delete. You can use something like hidden element or even ajax if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the id from the form and retrieve it in submit and then do the delete. You can use something like hidden element or even ajax if you want.
Try this

```
$button='<form method="post" action="remindMe.php">
           <input type="submit" value="Delete Post" name="delete" id='.$id.' />
           <input type="hidden" name="del_id" value='.$id.'>
         </form>';
```

//see if button is clicked

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  $delid = $_POST['del_id'];
  $query="UPDATE `task` SET `delete`=0 WHERE `id`= $delid";
  mysqli_query($con, $query)
    or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$button` variable presents inside `while` loop. So it may iterate with change of new `id` values. I didn't see `echo` statement in between your `while`

Either ways
If you want to using `POST` method, use `hidden` variables

```
//define delete button
$button='<form method="post" action="remindMe.php">
                 <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value='.$id.' />
                 <input type="submit" value="Delete Post" name="delete" id='.$id.' /> 
              </form>';
```

Add your query will be like this,

```
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$query="UPDATE `task` SET `delete`=0 WHERE `id`='".$post_id."'";
```